# How to check last FTP logins using SSH?

Tags: ssh, logging, ftp, vps, login

I've just bought a new VPS (its operating system is CentOS).
As this is my first experience with VPS, I don't know everything about managing and ...
One of my customers told me his website is not working like before. JavaScript files could not be loaded. When I checked the files on his hosting package, I saw 3 different unknown file (one cgi, one perl and one htaccess file).
I don't know how this files have been uploaded on his hosting space.
So I need to see last FTP logins attempts occurred on this account in 15 days ago.
How can I see this log through SSH ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/auth.log` (not sure if auth.log catches FTP logins) (all these files/path are for Ubuntu so you might want find equivalent for your system).
Basically, look in `/var/log` directory that is where all the logs are.
Hope this helps.

Comment: For CentOS, check `/var/log/{messages|secure|loginlog}`

Comment: I could find messages and secure, but loginlog was not there. Also, logs were not complate. Both of secure and messages showed just about 10 lines ...

Comment: check the `/var/log` directory. Older logs might have been logrotated

Answer (score 0):

For proftpd service works this two commands:

```
grep -R 'Login successful' /var/log/secure*

grep -R 'FTP session' /var/log/messages*
```